# How to get ratio between the count of two columns grouped together in mysql (leaderboard kill/death ratio)

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I've got a leaderboard in a pvp shooter game where I want to display the top 20 players ordered by their kill / death ratio (total kills divided by their total deaths)

I have a kills table that tracks kills and looks something like:

```
| killer_id | killed_id | date | 
| patrick   | jim       | 2021-03-01 |
| greyson   | jim       | 2021-03-02|
| jim       | patrick   | 2021-03-03|
```

I can get the total kills by doing something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_kills 
FROM kills 
GROUP BY killer_id 
ORDER BY total_kills DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

And I can get the total deaths by doing something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_deaths 
FROM kills 
GROUP BY killed_id 
ORDER BY total_deaths DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

However, I can't seem to group the query together so that I'm returning a list of the best ratios.  It would look like:

```
| player_id | kill_death_ratio (total kills / total deaths) |
| patrick   | 2.1            |
| jim       | 1.0            |
| greyson   | .9            |
```

Is this even possible in a single query?

Comment: `total_deaths` may be 0 for some players. What result do you expect in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT killer_id player_id FROM kills UNION SELECT killed_id FROM kills
```

to get all the players in the table.
Then join it with `LEFT` joins to your queries:

```
SELECT p.player_id, 
       COALESCE(t1.total_kills, 0) / t2.total_deaths kill_death_ratio
FROM (SELECT killer_id player_id FROM kills UNION SELECT killed_id FROM kills) p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT killer_id, COUNT(*) total_kills 
  FROM kills 
  GROUP BY killer_id 
) t1 ON t1.killer_id = p.player_id  LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT killed_id, COUNT(*) total_deaths 
  FROM kills 
  GROUP BY killed_id 
) t2 ON t2.killed_id = p.player_id
```

Or, without your queries:

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(killer) / SUM(killed) kill_death_ratio
FROM (
  SELECT killer_id player_id, 1 killer, 0 killed
  FROM kills
  UNION ALL
  SELECT killed_id, 0, 1
  FROM kills
) t
GROUP BY player_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d42c3430500d7d7cc8124425aa37954e).
Results (for your sample data):

| player_id | kill_death_ratio |
| --- | --- |
| jim | 0.5 |
| patrick | 1.0 |
| greyson | null |

Notice that you will get `null` for players that were never killed.

Comment: Incredible.  Thank you.  My kills table has close to 300k rows on it so this takes about 10 seconds to run so looks like some either caching of results or different approach is necessary but I've learned something.  FYI I wanted the ratio if you've never died to just be the number of kills so I used a COALESCE () to return the SUM(killer) in the case that returns null.